# Excel - Tell me the column header that had the highest number for each row

Tags: excel, identity-column

```
| Name  | Blues | Greens | Yellows | Reds | Winner |
| Smith | 35    | 42     | 52      | 17   |        |
```

I want to know the column header that has the largest number for each row and insert its name in the 'Winner' column.

How would this be done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using a formula like (suposing the headers on `A1:E1`)

`=OFFSET($A$1,0,MATCH(MAX($A2:$E2),$A2:$E2,0)-1)`

The `Match` function will give the position of the maximum value of the range `$A2:$E2`. Then you can use the`Offset` function to get the header on that position

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Rows are "A" for the Name, "B" - "E" for the values and "F" for
the winner, this works.

=IF(MAX(B3:E3)=B3;B$1;IF(MAX(B3:E3)=C3;C$1;IF(MAX(B3:E3)=D3;D$1;E$1)))